# Error in `cut` function

Tags: r, cut

I'm trying to group all dates houses in San Francisco were sold by year. I'm using the following code

```
geo_big$month <- as.Date(paste0(strftime(geo_big$date, format = "%Y-%m"), "-01"))

geo_big$date_r <- cut(geo_big$month, breaks = as.Date(c("2003-04-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-11-01")), include.lowest = TRUE, labels = as.Date(c("2003-01 - 2004-12", "2004-01 - 2004-12", "2005-01 - 2005-12", "2006-01 - 2006-12", "2007-01 - 2007-12", "2008-01 - 2008-11")))
```

And getting this message:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What format is `geo_big$date` stored as?

Comment: as.Date(strptime(geo_big$date, "%Y-%m-%d"))

Comment: One aspect that looks suspicious is the 'labels' argument. Should be a character vector rather than a Date. The other aspect that looks questionable (after looking at `help(cut.Date)` ) is the breaks argument. Testing with a sequence of Date values returns an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error given should indicate to you that the issue is not `cut` but `as.Date`.  (It's complaining to you about not being able to determine the format of the date)

More specifically, it is what you have givn as labels.  No need to wrap those in `as.Date`

The labels should be `character` and `c(.)` and the quotation marks are sufficient for that.

---

Just as a bit of hand, the code above can be cleaned up in a few areas.
Also, the `lubridate` package might be very useful to you.

```
# instead of: 
geo_big$month <- as.Date(paste0(strftime(geo_big$date, format = "%Y-%m"), "-01"))

# you can use `floor_date`: 
library(lubridate)
geo_big$month <- floor_date(geo_big$date, "month")  # from the `lubridate` pkg


# instead of: 
... a giant cut statement... 

# use variables for ease of reading and debugging

# bks <- as.Date(c("2003-04-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-11-01")) 
# or: 
bks <- c(dmin, seq.Date(ceiling_date(dmin, "year"), floor_date(dmax, "year"), by="year"), dmax)  # still using library(lubridate)

# basing your labels on your breaks helps guard against human error & typos
lbls <- head(floor_date(bks, "year"), -1)  # dropping the last one, and adding dmax
lbls <- paste( substr(lbls, 1, 7),   substr(c(lbls[-1] - 1, dmax), 1, 7), sep=" - ")

# a cleaner, more readable `cut` statement
cut(geo_big$month, breaks=bks, include.lowest=TRUE, labels=lbls)
```